# Credit card numbers stolen. How to check if my MacBook has a keylogger installed?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, safari

My credit card numbers have been stolen recently. I suspect that was because of my MacBook. I'm thinking that because I had never had the issue before, until recently, after I started using a MacBook Pro (and let Safari stored my card information).

List of Safari extensions that I installed:

- [AdGuard Adblocker](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.adguard.safari-N33TQXN8C7)
- [Translate](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=com.sidetree.Translate-S64NDGV2C5)

List of applications that I installed:

- MacTeX
- TeXstudio
- Visual Studio Code
- Google Chrome (just to check for passwords that I forgot so that I can use them again in Safari)
- Some fonts (Cambria Math, STIX Two, TeX Gyre)

I installed Malwarebytes and scanned my Mac but dit not find anything.

How can I check if my MacBook is keylogged?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer is you already have!**

Malwarebytes, like most (if not all) antivirus software for Macs, also guards against other nefarious activities, including keyloggers.

The free trial of Malwarebytes (which I assume is what you used to scan your Mac), would have identified any threats and cleaned your Mac of any infections. The free trial also comes with 30 days access to their premium service, so you could also take advantage of that as well.

Assuming you're a personal/home user, then many of the free options will most likely meet your needs, so don't feel obligated to keep using Malwarebytes if your preference is otherwise.

There are many other options out there you can choose from. As a starting point you can refer to the [AV Comparatives list of antivirus vendors for Mac](https://www.av-comparatives.org/list-of-av-vendors-mac/).

You may also want to read the most recent (as of now) [AV Comparatives Mac Security Test and Review](https://www.av-comparatives.org/tests/mac-security-test-review-2017/) report (conducted in 2017).